# mysql bulk update multiple records at once

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I have data such as:

```
id  table   column add edit delete view
1   vendors city    0   0   0      1
1   vendors state   0   0   0      1
1   vendors zip     0   0   0      1
```

And i am trying to perform a bulk update with a similar query:

```
UPDATE user_perms SET add = ?, edit = ?, delete = ?, view = ?
WHERE id = ? AND table_name = ? AND column_name = ?
```

Without having to loop through a list and run this query X number of times, does MySQL support a way to bulk update in 1 go?

CREATE TABLE STMT:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_perms` (
   `up_id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `table_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `column_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `add` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `edit` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `delete` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `view` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`up_id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `up_id_UNIQUE` (`up_id`),
   KEY `fk_idx` (`id`),
   CONSTRAINT `fk_id` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1659 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: no need a loop, it will update all matching record based on your `WHERE id = ?` where condition.

Comment: but I need to change the add, edit, delete, or view for various table + column combinations

Comment: Updates in SQL are, by default, bulk updates.  Meaning that an update can target as many records as your `WHERE` clause will allow.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, right but I might need combination of vendors + city to be 1, 1, 0, 0 while I need combination of vendors + zip to be 0, 1, 0, 1 so in that case how would you handle the bulk update?

Comment: @dataviews as per your table you are storing details of other table in above given table and dynamically u need to update, then may b u need loop.

Comment: You might be able to use `REPLACE` or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` if the `user_perms` table has a primary key or unique key. Can you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE user_perms` and edit the question above with the output?

Comment: Okay, thanks for including that. Unfortunately, my idea won't work, because the primary/unique key column is not referenced in your `UPDATE` statement. So my idea would just insert new rows, not update the existing rows.

Comment: @BillKarwin potentially, I thought of bulk deleting and then bulk inserting again the new records and values. But im not sure if this would be a good approach. Any thoughts?

Comment: Not related to your question, but be careful about using a column named `delete`. This is a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html), and you have to put it in back-quotes to use it as a column identifier.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the closest thing you could do to update multiple rows is to set the values using CASE expressions:

```
UPDATE user_perms 
SET add    = CASE column_name WHEN 'city' THEN ? WHEN 'state' THEN ? WHEN 'zip' THEN ? END,
    edit   = CASE column_name WHEN 'city' THEN ? WHEN 'state' THEN ? WHEN 'zip' THEN ? END,
    delete = CASE column_name WHEN 'city' THEN ? WHEN 'state' THEN ? WHEN 'zip' THEN ? END,
    view   = CASE column_name WHEN 'city' THEN ? WHEN 'state' THEN ? WHEN 'zip' THEN ? END
WHERE id = ? AND table_name = ?;
```

It would be even more complicated if you wanted to put both `table_name` and `column_name` into the CASE expression.

Frankly, it's easier to just write the loop and do this one row at a time.

If you had a unique key for example comprised of the columns `(id, table_name, column_name)` so SQL could detect when it was inserting a duplicate row, you could do the following:

```
INSERT INTO user_perms (id, table_name, column_name, add, edit, delete, view)
VALUES (1, 'vendors', 'city',  0, 0, 0, 1),
       (1, 'vendors', 'state', 0, 0, 0, 1),
       (1, 'vendors', 'zip',   0, 0, 0, 1) 
       -- any number of additional tuples follow
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE add = VALUES(add), edit = VALUES(edit), 
       delete = VALUES(delete), view = VALUES(view);
```

If this worked, you would not need to delete the rows first. [INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) is intended to insert a new row if the data you insert does not conflict with an existing row, but if the values you insert do conflict with a unique key on the table, it updates only those columns you set, according to the `UPDATE` clause. Read the documentation for more details.

Comment: so if you have to do this row by row, what happens if half way through something fails or exits? Would it be better to create a stored procedure and rollback if all updates fail?

Comment: If you do it in a loop one row at a time, you could rollback the whole batch if one fails, or if all fail, or whatever you want. Or you could ignore failures and commit as many as succeed. Up to you. I can't say what's "better" because it depends on what your project needs, and you know that more than I do.